# Possible to edit images dynamically and on the fly?

Tags: javascript

For example: Take a look at a character for my RPG browser game:
[image]

I want to add an attack weapon animation. But, I need to manipulate this .png image, and cut out a square box out of it, and then apply some css animations. (So it has the effect of swinging a weapon). I know how to do that part, but the problem is trying to cut out the image with Javascript and then use it as an individual, or it's own separate div. All the image character files are the same dimensions btw.

So, is it possible to manipulate images with Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, post it.

Comment: @NiCk - yes it is. Look into example that use the `<canvas>` element to do this. Specifically, look into (1) the drawImage method of the context and (2) the `toDataURL` method of the canvas.

Comment: you need to separate avatars from weapons so you could place any weapon image on top of an avatar. your solution of editing an already existing image that has both is doomed to fail

Comment: @vsycn yeah, I let users do that when using the Character Designer. Each part is an individual image (boots, gloves, helmet, weapons, shield, armor). But after they are done editing their character, I use PHP to securely render the image and create the their own character render. (checking if they own items, etc via mysql)

 But, your idea is better to just create a div container and make the illusion of the character instead of the render. Too lazy ^_^.

Comment: why do you combine it? I think you need to work with sprites, this is the way developers had done it for the past 30 years or so..each element is separate and independent. you just remember each character settings and how to "build" it using the different images at your disposal (in a spritely manner)

Comment: I am actually not sure why. I just thought it would be easier when people are entering/joining channels in the lobby. I don't need to grab all their items and then create the div container to make the illusion of their character, I could just call their character_image variable. I do wonder why because when equipping items the character isn't updated instantly... I don't want to render the character each time a user equips an item, so maybe I should do the div container illusion idea. (I already do it for the character designer, but not in general, hmm)

Comment: Then I could have access to animate their weapon or any item they have! (making their shield glow, or whatnot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's canvas object.

1. First load your PNG to canvas
2. Manipulate your image with canvas functions
3. Convert your canvas to image again

Comment: Totally forgot about canvas. Wow, my bad. I'll mark you as the answer in 9  minutes, thanks!